# How to disable another attribute's value, based on selected attribute values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, attributes, e-commerce

This is attributes obejct:

```
const attributes=[
  {
    "attribute_id": "1",
    "translation": {
      "en": {
        "name": "RAM"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "attribute_id": "2",
    "translation": {
      "en": {
        "name": "ROM"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "attribute_id": "3",
    "translation": {
      "en": {
        "name": "Camera"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is attribute values object:

```
const attribute_values=[
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "1",
    "attribute_value_id": "1",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "8 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "1",
    "attribute_value_id": "2",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "12 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "2",
    "attribute_value_id": "3",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "256 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "2",
    "attribute_value_id": "4",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "512 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "3",
    "attribute_value_id": "5",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "12 MP"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is variant combination:

```
const variants=[
  {
    "sku": "variant_1",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "RAM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "ROM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "Camera"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "attribute_values": [
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "8 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "attribute_Value_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "256 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "2",
        "attribute_Value_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 MP"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "3",
        "attribute_Value_id": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sku": "variant_2",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "RAM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "ROM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "Camera"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "attribute_values": [
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "attribute_Value_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "512 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "2",
        "attribute_Value_id": "4"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 MP"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "3",
        "attribute_Value_id": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sku": "variant_3",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "RAM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "ROM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "Camera"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "attribute_values": [
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "attribute_Value_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "256 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "2",
        "attribute_Value_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 MP"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "3",
        "attribute_Value_id": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When i choose any `attribute_value_id` from `attribute_values` object, it will set `isEnable` to false on `attribute_values` object based on `variants` object's `attribute_value_id`'s combination.

i'm expecting:
if i choose `attribute_value_id:"1"(8 GB)` then `attribute_value_id:"4"(512 GB)`'s isEnable property should be set to false, beacuse there is no variant combination with `attribute_value_id:1(8 GB)` and `attribute_value_id:4(512 GB)`

i'm trying this:

```js
const attributes=[
  {
    "attribute_id": "1",
    "translation": {
      "en": {
        "name": "RAM"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "attribute_id": "2",
    "translation": {
      "en": {
        "name": "ROM"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "attribute_id": "3",
    "translation": {
      "en": {
        "name": "Camera"
      }
    }
  }
]

const attribute_values=[
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "1",
    "attribute_value_id": "1",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "8 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "1",
    "attribute_value_id": "2",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "12 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "2",
    "attribute_value_id": "3",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "256 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "2",
    "attribute_value_id": "4",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "512 GB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "isEnable": true,
    "attibute_id": "3",
    "attribute_value_id": "5",
    "translations": {
      "en": {
        "name": "12 MP"
      }
    }
  }
]

const variants=[
  {
    "sku": "variant_1",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "RAM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "ROM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "Camera"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "attribute_values": [
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "8 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "attribute_Value_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "256 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "2",
        "attribute_Value_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 MP"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "3",
        "attribute_Value_id": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sku": "variant_2",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "RAM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "ROM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "Camera"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "attribute_values": [
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "attribute_Value_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "512 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "2",
        "attribute_Value_id": "4"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 MP"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "3",
        "attribute_Value_id": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sku": "variant_3",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "RAM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "ROM"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "translation": {
          "en": {
            "name": "Camera"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "attribute_values": [
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "1",
        "attribute_Value_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "256 GB"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "2",
        "attribute_Value_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "translations": {
          "en": {
            "name": "12 MP"
          }
        },
        "attribute_id": "3",
        "attribute_Value_id": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
]


const selectedAttributeValueIds = ["1"]; 

// Find the selected attribute values
const selectedAttributeValues = selectedAttributeValueIds.map((selectedId) =>
  attribute_values.find((value) => value.attribute_value_id === selectedId)
);

// Get the selected attribute_ids
const selectedAttributeIds = selectedAttributeValues.map((value) => value.attribute_id);

// Find the variant combinations that have the selected attribute values
const matchingVariantCombinations = variants.filter((variant) =>
  variant.attribute_values.every((attributeValue) =>
    selectedAttributeIds.includes(attributeValue.attribute_id) &&
    selectedAttributeValueIds.includes(attributeValue.attribute_Value_id)
  )
);

// Get the attribute_value_ids for other attributes in the matching variants
const matchingAttributeValues = matchingVariantCombinations.flatMap((variant) =>
  variant.attribute_values
    .filter(
      (attributeValue) =>
        !selectedAttributeIds.includes(attributeValue.attribute_id) &&
        !selectedAttributeValueIds.includes(attributeValue.attribute_Value_id)
    )
    .map((attributeValue) => attributeValue.attribute_Value_id)
);

// Disable attribute_values that are not present in matching variants
attribute_values.forEach((value) => {
  if (
    !selectedAttributeIds.includes(value.attribute_id) &&
    !selectedAttributeValueIds.includes(value.attribute_value_id) &&
    !matchingAttributeValues.includes(value.attribute_value_id)
  ) {
    value.isEnable = false;
  }
});


console.log(attribute_values);
```

Comment: Please show the code that's not working correctly.

Comment: Why do you have the same `attribute_id` in all the attributes?

Comment: Your life would be easier if you used objects whose keys are the unique IDs, rather than arrays that you have to search.

Comment: @Barmar Please check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j0z7wqcm/1/

Comment: Put the code in the question here. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar added my code in code snippet

Comment: `matchingAttributeValues` is empty, is that expected?

Comment: And `selectedAttributeIds` contains `[undefined]`, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: You have a typo: `attibute_id` should be `attribute_id`

Comment: Fixing that typo produces `isEnable: false` in the results.

Comment: What kind of debugging did you do? Didn't you try looking at the intermediate arrays to see if they contained the expected values? When they didn't you should figure out why.